# How to insert a new line after eof is reached in delphi

Tags: delphi

In below code i tried to add a new line after eof reached, but NULL is written at the end of last line. could anybody suggest me.

```
If ( nImportPos > 0 ) then begin 
  nImportPos := FileWrite(fHandle, #13, length(#13)); 
  FileSeek(fhandle,0,2);
end;
```

Comment: Also you should be writing #13#10 for a windows line end mark. Is it an ANSI or Unicode file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing to an ASCII or ANSI file then I would code it as follows:

```
if nImportPos>0 then begin
  Assert(StringElementSize(sLineBreak)=1);
  nImportPos := FileWrite(fHandle, sLineBreak[1], Length(sLineBreak));
end;
```

**Notes:**

1. The `StringElementSize` assertion is to justify the assumption, in the following line, that `sLineBreak` has single byte character elements. The definition of `sLineBreak` use `AnsiString` explicitly. If your Delphi is pre-Unicode then this line will not compile and you can remove it.
2. `sLineBreak` is the correct way to write a new line to an ASCII/ANSI file. On Windows it is defined to be `AnsiString(#13#10)`, i.e. a CR+LF pair. On Unix based platforms it is defined to be `AnsiString(#10)`, i.e. a single LF. Use `sLineBreak` to express logically what you are doing and let the compiler deal with the implementation.
3. The call to `FileSeek()` is not needed since `FileWrite()` moves the file pointer to the end of the buffer that `FileWrite()` writes.